# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Guys i kindly need your help to figure out why am getting this error when i ran my script on a server. the server runs a postgres db i think it is something to do with the object type of the data it's been iterated but not sure how to fix that.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/change_topup.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "scripts/change_topup.py", line 55, in main
    process_file(path)
  File "scripts/change_topup.py", line 45, in process_file
    for enrolment in enrolments:
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1074, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 52, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 848, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...n"."type" = 1 AND "registration_household"."name" IN (SELECT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

my script is here

```
# script to update hh top-up locations
import django
django.setup()


import sys
import sys
import xlrd
from django.db import transaction
from maidea.apps.enrolment.models import Enrolment
from maidea.apps.redemption.models import Retailer
from maidea.apps.registration.models import Household
from maidea.apps.interventions.models import Intervention
from maidea.apps.wfp.models import Office


office = Office.objects.get(slug='so-co')
intervention = Intervention.objects.get(project__office=office, slug='cash-for-dadaab-returnees')

print("Using Office: {0}".format(office))
print("Using Intervention: {0}".format(intervention))

def process_file(path):
    # get the first worksheet
    book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    print('Sheet name: {0}'.format(first_sheet.name))

    print("Looping through excel rows. Please wait ...")
    #counter = 0

    with transaction.atomic():
        # iterate through rows
        for row_idx in range(1, first_sheet.nrows):
            # household names
            hh_name = str(first_sheet.row_values(row_idx)[0])
            # the new top-up locations
            new_top_up = str(first_sheet.row_values(row_idx)[2])


            households = Household.objects.filter(name__in=hh_name)
            top_up = Retailer.objects.filter(name__in=new_top_up) 
            enrolments = Enrolment.objects.filter(intervention=intervention, household__name__in=households) 
            #print("Fetched {0} enrolments".format(enrolments.count())
            for enrolment in enrolments:
                print enrolment
                # enrolment.retailer = top_up
                # enrolment.save()
                #counter += 1
            print("{0} enrolments updated".format(counter))


def main():
    path = "/opt/cv_instances/cv1/autodeploy/branches/nboreports/maidea/somalia/data_import_files/Enrolment.xlsx"
    process_file(path)
    print("DONE PROCESSING FILE.")

main()
```

The file been processed has rows  like

### HH             | top up                |

### SD803-11H47782 | MERCY US NEW POS TOPUP

SD803-09H03991 | DRC-MOG

Help will highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: You need to add your models as well.

Comment: As ettanany said we need your models for the "Enrolment" class so we can see what type it is in your Database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
enrolments = Enrolment.objects.filter(intervention=intervention, household__name__in=households):
```

households is a queryset of `Household` instances, not names. I think that either of the following would work.

```
enrolments = Enrolment.objects.filter(intervention=intervention, household__in=hh_name) 


enrolments = Enrolment.objects.filter(intervention=intervention, household__name__in=hh_name)
```

If you use the second one, then it looks like you can remove the `households` queryset from your code.

Comment: it worked the issue was from my enrolment queryset that could not filter the household name object thanks